# Limiting Query Result to number of rows of ONE of 2 JOINED tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I intend to LIMIT the result of my query to the rows from the Section Table(126 rows)
But my query keeps giving either 725 rows for Event Table(QUERY 1) OR Error message (QUERY 2)
How do I write this JOIN query and limit the output to the number of rows in Section Table?

QUERY 1

```
SELECT      
CASE WHEN e.EventActive='y' 
THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END AS EventActive, 
COUNT(*) AS 'Total'
FROM       ADF_Section s
INNER JOIN ADF_Event e
ON          s.SectionID = e.SectionID
GROUP BY
CASE WHEN e.EventActive='y' 
THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END
```

QUERY 2

```
SELECT      s.*, e.EventActive
FROM        ADF_Section s
INNER JOIN ADF_Event e
ON         s.SectionID = e.SectionID
HAVING     s.CourseID<= 1037
GROUP BY   s.*, e.EventActive
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can clearly have more than 1 `Event` per `Section`. In order to provide a correct answer to your question, you need to specify what should be returned in case a Section has both Active and Inactive events.

Comment: Thank you, w0lf, for pointing that out. In the case of BOTH Active and INACTIVE Events then it will be NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `exists`:

```
SELECT s.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM ADF_EVENT e
                          WHERE s.SectionID = e.SectionID AND e.EventActive = 'y'
                         )
             THEN 'y' ELSE 'n'
        END) as EventActive
FROM  ADF_Section s
WHERE s.CourseID <= 1037;
```

If you have a lot of data, this would benefits from indexes:  `ADF_Section(CourseId, SectionId)` and `ADF_Event(SectionId, EventActive)`.

Note:  This assumes an event is active when any event associated with the section is active.  If the logic is really that *all* need to be active and there is at least one, the following logic should work:

```
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM ADF_EVENT e
                          WHERE s.SectionID = e.SectionID
                          GROUP BY e.SectionId
                          HAVING MIN(EventActive) = MAX(EventActive) AND MIN(EventActive) = 'y'
                         )
             THEN 'y' ELSE 'n'
```

Comment: THank you Gordon Linoff. I ran the query and got 126 rows. Nothing extra. This is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can compute the Active/Inactive status per Section:

```
select s.SectionID, 
  case 
    -- if all Events in the series are 'y, 
    -- Section is considered 'Active':
    when min(e.EventActive) = 'y' and max(e.EventActive) = 'y' then 'Active'

    -- there are both active and inactive Events,
    -- display NULL (according to your comment):
    when min(e.EventActive) < max(e.EventActive) then null

    -- in case none of the above scenarios are met, 
    -- it means that all Events are inactive, so we 
    -- consider Section to be inactive as well:
    else 'Inactive'
  end as EventActive
from ADF_Section s
join ADF_Event e
  on s.SectionID = e.SectionID
group by s.SectionID;
```

I have created a test scenario with some random data here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa0a3/1

If you need to filter `Section`s based on `CourseID`, add this filter in a `WHERE` clause and make sure to include the filtered fields in the `GROUP BY` as well:

```
select s.SectionID, 
  case 
    when min(e.EventActive) = 'y' and max(e.EventActive) = 'y' then 'Active'
    when min(e.EventActive) < max(e.EventActive) then null
    else 'Inactive'
  end as EventActive
from ADF_Section s
join ADF_Event e
  on s.SectionID = e.SectionID
where s.CourseId <= 1037
group by s.SectionID, s.CourseID;
```

Comment: Thank you w0lf. I ran your 2nd query. It worked, but gave me 115 rows. I should be able to tweak it and derive all 126 rows.

Comment: @Eda That's probably because of the `s.CourseId <= 1037` condition.

Comment: You got it! That is exactly what it needs